# IMPORTRANGE() based on the date of another cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use IMPORTRANGE() to import a sheet from another spreadsheet. I am currently using the following formula.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("URL", B1&"!A1:R25")
```

However, I am getting stuck with the sheet name. B1 is a cell that shows a date, consequently I want to import the sheet with that date as its name. Also, B1 determines that date based on a formula; here it is

```
=(Leftb(Summary!$A$2,2)&"-"&Midb(Summary!$A$2,3,2)&"-"&rightb(Summary!$A$2,2))+7
```

I believe since B1 contains a formula like this, something is getting messed up in the importrange(), either the formula or the format of the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current formula gets the **value** of the date, not the date that is displayed in the `UI`.

Try this formula:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("URL", TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,B1)&"!A1:R25")
```

---

[image: RESULT]

Comment: Reference to [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en). This function is basically making a string out of the date value ignoring empty cells.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf true! Thanks for the additional info Mateo ;)